# Sencha vs SprouteCore

Tags: mobile, extjs, web, sproutcore

I need to develop web based mobile apps, and considering mobile frameworks. 
What's easier to learn? what support more devices? please give me directions

Answer (score 0):

[Trends](http://www.google.com/trends?q=sencha%20touch,%20jquery%20mobile,%20jqtouch&ctab=0&geo=all&date=all&sort=0)

JQuery mobile strives for the widest range of support ( which for me is the clincher )

As to whats easier? 
That depends on what you know ( for example, I was able to pickup sencha touch quite easily because I already did quite a bit with extjs and the syntax is very similar, I would imagine this is true for Jquery mobile and jquery aswell )